# Entry.get() Error in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to delete a record when the ID is inserted or the Name of the Recipe is entered by the user into the entry boxes. However it will not let me obtain the information from the entry box due to the following error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\A-Level Computing\PROJECT!\Final Code.py", line 368, in delete_recipe
  Retrieve1 = EntryBox1.get()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"
```

The code is as follows:

```
def delete_recipe():

    global EntryBox1, EntryBox2, new_db

    Retrieve1 = EntryBox1.get()
    Retrieve2 = EntryBox2.get()

    new_db = sqlite3.connect('H:\A-Level Computing\PROJECT!\Recipes.db')

    new_db.execute("DELETE from RecipesDetails WHERE Retrieve1 = Rec_ID and Retrieve2 = Name")

    new_db.commit()
    new_db.close()
```

I would be really grateful for any help;. Thanks!

Comment: Simple: `EntryBox1` is `None`. Where do you create/set it?

Comment: Once you fix `EntryBox1`, you may want to add `r` to create a raw string literal for proper rendering of backslashes: `new_db = sqlite3.connect(r'H:\A-Level Computing\PROJECT!\Recipes.db')`

Comment: My guess would be you have some helper function for creating all those Entry boxes and this function does not return anything...

Comment: `v = StringVar()
    self.EntryBox1 = Entry(name_of_frame, textvariable=v)
    self.EntryBox1.pack()
    self.EntryBox1.place(x,y)` now you can do a `self.EntryBox1.get()` (`self`, naturally, assume you're encapsulated within a `class`)
Data within the `Entry` needs to be placed within an object to be retrieved as well as the creation of the `Entry` object, thus the reason for `StringVar() `

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a line like the following:

```
entry = Entry().pack() # entry is None
```

`pack`, `grid`, `place` does return `None`. `entry` become `None`.

You should separate the `Entry` creatation and call to `pack`/`grid`/`place` method:

```
entry = Entry()
entry.pack()
```